# Set DataGridView arrow to the selected row

Tags: c#, datagridviewcolumn

How do I set the arrow to the selected row. I'm programatically selecting the rows based on the value of a combo box. Currently, only the row is highlighted and the arrow doesn't follow

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
{
    if ((int)row.Tag == ma.ID)//ma.ID is the selected combo box value
    {
        row.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change `CurrentCell` like this. 
(This will also change `CurrentRow`)

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
{
    if ((int)row.Tag == ma.ID)//ma.ID is the selected combo box value
    {
        row.Selected = true;
        dgv.CurrentCell = row.Cells[0];
    }
}
```